# AngularJS ui-router template does not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I'm new to AngularJS. I've following egghead.io I've set up a controller and model to retrieve message from input component and display it. I'm using ui-router.

Here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> </title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view=""></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my app.js

```
angular.module('app',["ui.router"])

            .config([function($stateProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('index', {
                        url:"",                 
                        templateUrl:"templates/first.html",
                        controller:"FirstCtr as first"
                    });

            });

            .controller("FirstCtr", function FirstCtr() {
                var first = this;
                first.greeting = "First";

            });
```

Here's my templates/first.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting"/>
    <div ng-class="first.greeting">
        {{first.greeting}} {{"World"}}
    </div>
```

After I go to http://localhost:8080, it was blank and throw this error

[image]

Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state definition should be be declared controller alias in `controllerAs` option of state, with it you need to remove the semicolon from config block end.

Also you need to inject `$stateProvider` dependency properly to avoid error.

**Code**

```
angular.module('app', ["ui.router"])

//missed `'$stateProvider'` dependency here
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: "",
      templateUrl: "templates/first.html",
      controller: "FirstCtr",
      controllerAs: "first"
    });
}]) //remove semicolon from here as you are appending app in chain

.controller("FirstCtr", function FirstCtr() {
  var first = this;
  first.greeting = "First";
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBsmndU1M6vHyvf7EGbJ?p=preview)

Comment: I got 'SyntaxError: missing } after property list in app.js' and [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.'

Comment: @user3698126 that was my bad.. take a look at update..should work for sure 100%

Comment: I'm sorry, but I got SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' and [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @user3698126 now take a update again..should fixed now..Also look at error for further detail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84742/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-user3698126).